# How do I correlate the `int` hash value of a spaCy Token `ent_type` to a string?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Is there some way to decode the hash of spaCy token entity types without accessing the `ent_type_` attribute?

For example:

```py
for token in doc:
    hash_val = token.ent_type
    string_repr = some_map[hash_val]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's stored in the vocab.

```
nlp.vocab.strings[token.ent_type] == token.ent_type_
```

Not sure why you would need to do that though.